# bind onload with coldfusion

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, bind

Using coldfusion and a cfc I have a dynamic form the load and changes. I work fine when I test via localhost and locally on the server however when I try to use it via the URL it does not load. I cannot seem to figure out the issues. The site is jowa-usa.us the contact us page. Also please find the code below.

********Form*********

```
<cfform name = "form" action="contactus.cfm" method="Post"> 
        <cfselect name="Market" bindOnLoad="Yes" bind="cfc:data.getMarket()"/><br>
        <cfselect name="Country" bindOnLoad="Yes" bind="cfc:data.getCountry()"/> <br>
        <cfselect name="State" bindOnLoad="Yes" bind="cfc:data.getState({Country})" /><br><br>         
        <cfinput type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" validate="required"> 
    </cfform>
```

*******data.cfc*******

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cffunction displayname="getCountry" name="getCountry" access="remote" returntype="array">

        <cfquery name="Country" datasource="Replist"> 
            SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM dbo.SPCompanies
            ORDER BY Country
        </cfquery>
        <cfset count="1" />
        <cfset results = arraynew(2)>
        <cfloop query="Country">
            <cfset results[count][1]="#country#" />
            <cfset results[count][2]="#country#" />
            <cfset count= count+1>
        </cfloop>
        <cfreturn results />
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="getState" access="remote" returntype="array">
        <cfargument name="country" type="string" required="true">

        <cfquery name="State" datasource="Replist">
            SELECT DISTINCT State FROM dbo.SPCompanies
            WHERE country = '#country#'
            ORDER BY state
        </cfquery>
        <cfset count="1" />
        <cfset results = arraynew(2)>

        <cfloop query="State">
            <cfset results[count][1]="#state#" />
            <cfset results[count][2]="#state#" />
            <cfset count= count+1>
        </cfloop>
        <cfreturn results />
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="getMarket" access="remote" returntype="array">
        <cfquery name="Market" datasource="Replist">
            SELECT DISTINCT Market FROM dbo.SPCompanies
            ORDER BY market
        </cfquery>
        <cfset count="1" />
        <cfloop query="Market">
            <cfset results[count][1]="#market#" />
            <cfset results[count][2]="#market#" />
            <cfset count= count+1>
        </cfloop>
        <cfreturn results />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

---

Any help would be much apreciated, as I have been struggling to understand why this works only when you go localhost or 127.0.0.1 and not when you visit the site.

Comment: (Edit- remove direct link) While I would recommend using jquery instead, the CF UI stuff depends on various client side files located in `/CFIDE/scripts/*`. Do a view source of that page you will see several *.js includes. Those files do not seem to be accessible on your server. For example, `{yoursite}/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js` returns a 404 error.

Comment: Do you have any good examples on how to do this in jquery, I am not  the best at development. A site that has an example would be perfect and i'm sure I would be able to figure it out.

Comment: Also how do I make the scripts available? I just checked the server and the file that you said was there.

Comment: I do not know of any off-hand, but if you do a search for jquery related or cascading selects there are tons of examples. As far as the error, the files may be there but they are not accessible via url. So I suspect your site is missing the proper CFIDE/scripts mapping or virtual directory. Read over one of the [CF LockDown guides](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2014/6/24/ColdFusion_Lockdown_Security_guides) for how to do it safely. Important: The Administrator directory should NOT be public.

Comment: Glad to see it is working now. Don't forget to review the security guides. It is important to lock down your admin directory from the general public.